# Switch baseLayers according user preferences onLoad (init()) - OpenLayers - 3

Tags: javascript, switch-statement, openlayers-3, layer, radix

I'm working on a project where I need to switch the base layer, according to the user preferences with the inicial zoom (already working). I don't really know where, but i've seen that by default, the base layer "Google Satellite" is the one selected. I've tried to do by triggering a click on the wanted radio button and, the radio button get clicked visually, but nothing happend (the map selected is always "Satellite", no matter if I triggered a click or I don't know). I have tried SO MANY THINGS but this is like wet soap in my hands... when I think i have got the right way, it slides away

```
function zoominicial(){
    $.getJSON('servicos/usuario.svc/getZoomInicial', function (data) {
        var ret = data.d;
        var bsNum;
        if (ret != "ERRO") 
        {
            if(!ret){
                zoomtoextent();
            }
            else 
            {
                var base_Layer = ret.split(';')[1];
                var extentUsuario = ret.split(';')[0].split(',');
                var bsType;

                switch(base_Layer){

                    case "Google Satellite":
                    $(".baseLayersDiv input")[0].click();
                    $(".baseLayersDiv input")[0].checked = true;
                    bsNum = 0;
                    bsType = "satellite";
                    checkRadio();
                    break;

                    case "Google Hybrid":
                    $(".baseLayersDiv input")[1].click();
                    $(".baseLayersDiv input")[1].checked = true;
                    bsNum = 1;
                    bsType = "hybrid";
                    checkRadio();
                    break;

                    case "Google Street Maps":
                    $(".baseLayersDiv input")[2].click();
                    $(".baseLayersDiv input")[2].checked = true;
                    bsNum = 2;
                    bsType = "roadmap";
                    checkRadio();
                    break;

                    case "Sem Foto":
                    $(".baseLayersDiv input")[3].click();
                    $(".baseLayersDiv input")[3].checked = true;
                    bsNum = 3;
                    checkRadio();
                    break;
                }   

                function checkRadio(){
                    var radioBs = $('input:radio[name="' + map.layers[bsNum].name + '"]');
                    if(radioBs.is(':checked') === false) {
                        radioBs.filter('[value=' + map.layers[bsNum].value + ']').prop('checked', true);
                    }
                }

                if (map.baseLayers == undefined || map.baseLayers == "")
                    map.layers[bsNum].type = bsType;
                else
                    map.baseLayers.type = bsType;

                map.zoomToExtent(extentUsuario,map.layers[bsNum].projection);

                $(".baseLayersDiv input").on("click", function(){
                        $(".baseLayersDiv input")[bsNum].checked= true;
                    });
                $(""+map.layers[bsNum].id+"").trigger( "select" );

                var linkEl = $('label[for="'+""+ $(".baseLayersDiv input")[bsNum].id +""+'"]');

                if ( linkEl.click() === undefined ) {
                    document.location = linkEl.attr ( 'index.aspx' );
                } 
                else {
                    linkEl.click();  
                    $(".baseLayersDiv input")[bsNum].click();
                }
            }
        }

        else {
            $.messager.alert('cGIS', 'Não foi possível exibir o zoom inicial.');
        }

        setTimeout(2000);

    });
}
```

You see... I have tried every way to make the selection of the base layer but with no success.

I just can't reach the attributes of determinated base layer, because the children of the array of radio buttons are encapsulated. Does someone knows how to do it, PLEASE? I'm about to get crazy and throw my desk through the window!

Comment: Pure OpenLayers 3 doesn't support Google layers, and you code doesn't look like OpenLayers.  I suspect you are using a different package such as OLGM.  You should tag the question appropriately.

Comment: I'm sorry I should have explained that the base layers are already created and in perfect use. The question is that I wanted to pass the base layer from the user preferences toghether with the inicial zoom, then I've putted it inside "function zoominicial()"

It all works perfectly, recognizing all functions, and the radio button appears checked(or selected), but no action is done (the map type is always "satellite" when the page is refreshed)

Answer (score 0):

You have to find where all of the layers are defined or know where the instances are stored and call function setVisible(false) to all of them except the one you would like to have active on the begening. Changing unbined radio buttons wont change anything. Better would be to initialize them with the corresponding value to "visible" parameter. All layers are visible by deafault, and in case of full raster layers you will see only the top one.

[OL - setVisible API](https://openlayers.org/en/v4.6.5/apidoc/ol.layer.Base.html#setVisible)